# Django form generated twice

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I was wrapping my simple django application form in some `css` and realized that my form is being generated twice (Image below)[image]

I want it in the form of a table as you can see int he code below I explicitly wrap the form in a table. Yet the form appears above the table  and then again in the table. I have rechecked my code but cant seem to figure out what the issue is

Relevant Code - template where form is being generated

```
<a href="/ad_accounts"> All Accounts </a>
<br />
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <form action="." method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <thead>
        <th>Attribute</th>
        <th>Value</th>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>
            {{ form.title }}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Objective</td>
        <td><select class="select2_single form-control" tabindex="-1">
            <option value={{ form.objective }}</option>
                </select></td>
    </tr>
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <tr>
        <td><input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
    </tr>
    </form>
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class CampaignForm(forms.Form):
    """ Form for creating new Campaign """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        objectives = kwargs.get('objectives')
        if objectives:
            kwargs.pop('objectives')
        else:
            objectives = list()
        super(CampaignForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['title'] = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
        self.fields['objective'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=objectives)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{{ form.as_p }}` is the django built in way of rendering form. You were also manually rendering the same thing, so doing that might be unnecessary.

See django doc about [render form in template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates).

Comment: d'oh! Thanks for help